# How to prevent remounting of component when changing route in react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I want to prevent a component from remounting when I return back to it from some other component.

Example,

```
function App() {
   <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route exact path="/about">
      <About />
    </Route>
   </Switch>
}
```

If I go to `/about` and return back to `/`, I do not want to run the `useEffect` again for the Home component as I am using firestore real-time update for updating the posts on Home page and when useEffect is run, it again fetches all the posts from firstore.

Is there a way by which I can prevent the Home component from remounting?

Comment: I think you would have to use a custom hook because useEffect always runs on remount. Also you want the component to 'remount' this is how you display it. I think you could clarify that you want it to remount but you don't want the useEffect to fire.

Comment: Rather than trying to circumvent default behavior (i.e., unmounting on route change), I'd recommend considering relocating your call to firestore to the `App` component, which won't get unmounted. Pass the info you need to the `Home` component.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to have the `Home` component to stay mounted you are likely going to need to 'unmount' it with css. So if the route isn't exactly `'/'` you would add `display: none;` to the app component.

You could also structure the component to `return null` when the route isn't `'/'` and return the desired markup otherwise. This way you can always mount it but wouldn't render anything.

I think better than either of these would be to wrap your `Switch` with a context and initiate your fetch from this context. Then you can control have one source of control for your firestore fetch and just read from the context as needed. This video shows an example of this https://youtu.be/PKwu15ldZ7k?t=963